# Webpack wont transpile a correct React/JSX file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have this React file that I got from an example that works on codepen. When I use webpack on it, I get the following error: [Transpile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMC5n.png)
Why am I running into this issue.

Comment: It seems you haven't  configured your babelrc properly. Can you add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function is a ES6+/ES7 feature. You must to install and configure  Babel Stage 1 preset

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/

You can read details about this here: https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb  (Event handlers with arrow functions)